# How to get Threads of a Process and show it in a list

Tags: .net, vb.net

So In VB.NET I want to get all the threads associated with a Process, So I have a Textbox in which I type the process name then click the button to get all the thread associated with it in a list which I have on the Form. Thanks

I have tried to change it and tried searching it on internet, but did not got solution.

```
Imports System.Diagnostics
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.ComponentModel

Public Class Form1

    Private Sub ListThreads()
        Try
            Dim TheProcess As Process() = Process.GetProcessesByName(txtprocessName.Text)
            MessageBox.Show(txtprocessName.Text)

            Dim CurrentProcess As Process = Process.GetCurrentProcess()
            Dim myThreads As ProcessThreadCollection = CurrentProcess.Threads
            Dim thread As Process
            threadList.BeginUpdate()
            threadList.Clear()
            'threadList.Columns.Add("Name", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
            threadList.Columns.Add("ID", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Left)
            threadList.Columns.Add("Priority", 60, HorizontalAlignment.Right)
            threadList.Columns.Add("Start Time", 100, HorizontalAlignment.Right)
            For Each thread In myThreads
                Dim lvi As ListViewItem = New ListViewItem()
                'lvi.Text = thread.ProcessName
                lvi.SubItems.Add(thread.Id)
                lvi.SubItems.Add(thread.BasePriority)
                lvi.SubItems.Add(thread.StartTime)
                threadList.Items.Add(lvi)
            Next thread
            threadList.EndUpdate()
        Catch e As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(e.Message)
        End Try

    End Sub

    Private Sub btnShow_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnShow.Click
        ListThreads()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Every-time I run it It shows me a error
`Unable to cast object of type System.Diagnostics.ProcessThread to type System.Diagnostics.Process`

I want to get the threads associated with a process and show it in the list. Thanks

Comment: `For Each thread In myThreads` is the issue. The `thread` variable type is defined as `Process`, **but** you are getting a collection of `ProcessThread`'s, *not* `Process`. To fix, change the type of `thread` to `ProcessThread`; so `Dim thread As ProcessThread` . Also on another note, you don't need the variable `thread` just for the loop, just use `For Each thread As ProcessThread In myThreads`.

Comment: Thanks, I have changed it, Now the error is gone. But still threads of the process are not showing in the list. List is just empty.

Comment: Please see my last sentence in my comment.

Comment: sir I did as you said, It showing this error now "Variable 'thread' hides a variable in an enclosing block."

Comment: Please don't deface your question.  Add additional information to it as needed - but questions are not polymorphic and should not become a moving target.  Also, leaving the question intact after obtaining an answer allows others to search by their question to find this same answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main issue is because the type of `thread` is `Process`, but you are returning a collection of `ProcessThread`'s (`Dim myThreads As ProcessThreadCollection = CurrentProcess.Threads`), they are not the same.

To fix you have a few options:

1. Change the type of `thread` to `ProcessThread`. For ex: `Dim thread As ProcessThread` (this will fix the actual error).
2. Remove the variable `thread` altogether and change your loop; you should do this. For ex:

   `For Each thread As ThreadProcess In myThreads`

Comment: thanks for your help, I did everything the same but now the last and little problem coming is that its not showing the Threads in the list. So now program is working fine but when I put a process name and click the button nothing happens. So list is showing empty

Comment: If there are more issue's please create another question which includes a sample that we can run/replicate; don't keep adding more and more issues on this question as it can get confusing. If the answer solved your issue, please vote and or marked as answered.

Comment: Sir that's the last thing in my program to get threads in the list. Please could you help me out thanks.

Comment: @SMG I would love to, I am sure there are other's as well. Please create another question with the **other issue/s** you are seeing that's not related so other's can chime in as well.

Comment: No, create *another new question*, don't change this one.

Comment: Sir I cant create the new question, Its showing me to wait for 90 minutes for next post :(

Comment: Then please wait, when you update this post other users will not see the *new* problem.

Comment: Still can't post the new question, I dont know why its again showing the same message.

Comment: @SMG then try and ping a moderator, I would help if I could; why did you remove the check mark as answered?

Comment: I thought maybe someone could come and help me out. But thank you very much for helping me out in this. Now this last thing is making me crazy.